# how to float a div below the carousel? using html and css only

Tags: html, css

[the layout I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwMZU.png)

Can anyone help me how to put the div below the carousel? I'm kinda new to this

Comment: Where is your code? What did you try?

Comment: What is your effort so far?

Comment: <header>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="column1">
    <img src="img/1.png" style="width:650px; height:176px;" alt="Tax Refund Guru">
   </div>
   <div class="column2">
    <img src="img/2.png"></br>
    <img style ="margin-left: 230px;" src="img/fb.png">
    <img src="img/twi.png">
    <img src="img/yout.png">
    <img src="img/insta.png">
    <img src="img/thumb.png">
    <img src="img/pin.png">
    <img src="img/in.png">
   </div>
  <div>
 </header>

Comment: <div>
    <ul class="nav">
   <li style="border-left: 1px solid #04db88;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tax Preparation</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tax Problems</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">My Tax Vault</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">TRG Agent Hub</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Small Business</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

Comment: <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/slide1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/slide2.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/slide3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/slide4.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: this part should be the div below the carousel but I dont know how

Comment: <div class="b">
 
 </div>

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to send the whole script here

Comment: @Kloe add code in your question instead of comments

Comment: @Kloe just add stack snippet

Comment: @Kole click - post your answer- and then write there

Comment: @Kloe give the `<div class="carousel">` a `z-index: 10;` in your css.  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @Kloe I also added an answer with a demonstration, where I tried to reproduce your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the carrousel a `z-index: 5;` and `position: relative;` and give the div you want under it a `position: relative;` and `top: -value` where value is the pixels you want it to go up.

Instead of the `<div class="carousel">` use your  own carrousel div. and same with the header.

> For more info on how `z-index` works visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```css
header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: RGBA(0,255,0,0.4);
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.classname {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}

header,
nav{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.carousel{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.classname{
 text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
  <nav>
    Nav
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="carousel">
  Carousel
</div>
<div class="classname"> DIV below carousel</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. Using margin top.

JSFiddel Link: https://jsfiddle.net/VrtuosArs/9h8djmy2/1/

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

header {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0.1rem;
}

.headertext {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

nav {
  background: #FF9EC5;
  padding: 0.1rem;
}

#carousel {
  background: #9BFF00;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#bcarousel {
  background: #95D6ED;
}

.dac {
  height: 240px;
  margin-top: -2rem;
}

footer {
  background: #C2C2C2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Div carousel</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.0.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center headertext">Header</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center headertext">Navbar</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="carousel">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
      <h1 class="text-center headertext">Carousel</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="bcarousel">
  <div class="row dac">
    <div class="col-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
      <h3 class="text-center headertext">Div below carousel</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center headertext">Footer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```